How to filter an API Resource based on a Policy
I'm needing to filter a collection based on a defined policy. But get nothing back, can someone point me in the right direction.
Perhaps it's possible to do the check in the controller. However, it seems logical to do it in the API Resource. As I understand it, the whole point of the API Resource is to serve a model OR a collection of models in custom & tailored way.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'role' => $this->role->name,
            'accessible_projects' => $this->client->projects->filter(function ($item)
                {
                    Auth::user()->can('view', $item);
                }
            ),    
        ];
    }
}


You are not returning anything in the filter callback.
Take a look at the documentation for the filter method.
You need something like return Auth::user()->can('view', $item);
So the full code would look like;
return [
    'name' => $this->name,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'client_id' => $this->client->id,
    'role' => $this->role->name,
    'accessible_projects' => $this->client->projects->filter(function ($item)
        {
            return Auth::user()->can('view', $item);
        }
    ),    
];


Thanks, heaps. Also, just wondering if it's an appropriate overall pattern?

Not quite sure, I don't see anything wrong with it really, but I'm not up-to-date with best practices in this instance. I guess it could be pretty resource-intensive if you have a lot of users.
